# I would like to have an echo in 1 line for my ASCII art but I can't manage. PLS Help

Tags: bash, fedora, echo, ascii

I would like to have an echo in 1 single line for my ASCII art but I can't manage. PLS Help

link to my ASCII:
https://ascii-generator.site/r/Mor3V1/

PLS Help it is urgent

Comment: What is meant by "echo"?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498279/edit) and add the bash script you have written and format is as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window. To use the command echo, type `echo "Hello World"`, and you will get "Hello World" in one line. Explain your problem better for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo apt install figlet
...

$ figlet "Fjord OS"
 _____ _               _    ___  ____  
|  ___(_) ___  _ __ __| |  / _ \/ ___| 
| |_  | |/ _ \| '__/ _` | | | | \___ \ 
|  _| | | (_) | | | (_| | | |_| |___) |
|_|  _/ |\___/|_|  \__,_|  \___/|____/ 
    |__/                               

$ showfigfonts 
...

$ man figlet
...
```